# In hibernate Query fails to load list during search

Tags: java, hibernate

My query is fetching data from oracle DB to a list but, once I try to search it fails and returns an empty list without generating any errors.

Access HBL query from Data Access Obj Classes

```
public List<TrxCmpComplaint> readwithParam(int sbu,int br, String usr) {
        try {
            sess = sf.openSession();
            trx = sess.beginTransaction();
            Query q = sess.createQuery("from TrxCmpComplaint  where cfgCmpSbu.sbuid=:sbu and cfgCmpBranch.brid=:br and ((marktousername=:usr or complainantemp=:usr) or dgusername=:usr) ORDER BY statusid asc, CMPID desc");
            q.setParameter("sbu", sbu);
            q.setParameter("br", br);
            q.setParameter("usr", usr);
            List<TrxCmpComplaint> list = q.list();
            return list;
        } catch (HibernateException hex) {
            hex.getMessage();
            hex.getLocalizedMessage();
            hex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.flush();
            sess.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I removed parameters of `sbu` and `br` (sbu and br is entity objects that refer to state of database field) the search query works for me. Please assist me that why my code fails during search?

Comment: Not sure if filterMatchMode=contains is applicable for numeric fields. Please edit your post adding a [mcve] and fix formatting and tagging.

Comment: Tagging because it is very, very broad (and 'swing'???). Narrow down your problem The datatable is not searching, your code does. And also correct your title since it is almost a summary of tags. See [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and

Comment: Where are br and sbu comming from? How

Comment: @SimonMartinelli br and sbu are entity objects that refer in hbl query as database fields.

Comment: But you say "f I removed parameters of sbu and br (sbu and br is entity objects that refer to state of database field) the search query works for me" then the parameters are the problem

Comment: parameters are problem because hibernate query with mapping of table is not searching  in datatable. Sbu and Br are act as foreign id in this table.

Comment: @BalusC I have no idea how to invoke parameters during hbl query or how to search in datatable during HBL mapping query. It created trouble only with parameter assign. I dont knw why it is working if i removed parameters. Nor it is generating any error except class def not found.

Comment: Please show your entity mapping. I don't understand your problem. Do you get any error messages?